# programatic actions in Kaleo workflow

Tags: groovy, liferay, workflow

I started learn Liferay (6.2 EE trial packaged with glassfish) Kaleo workflow, and as I see its documentation is a joke. Anyway, can someone give me examples how can I initiate a DB function and/or write a file and/or call a webservice from a kaloe activity.
I downloaded the liferay developer studio (not the ide) and connected to that glassfish based local liferay server.

I know I have to write scripts, seems Groovy should be choosen language for it, but not familiar with it at all, and did not found any usefull example on the web.

So pls pls pls give me some example and if additional configuration is needed for an example then pls give me a step by step instruction for that configuration.

---

Where and what kind of log should I check if an activity script failed/wrong/throw and exception etc?

---

Is some debuging function available for those scripts? For example does a println function work and if yes where can I see the result?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing more complex operations in your workflow, the recommendation is to implement them in services - they're a lot easier to debug, have proper tooling etc. Scripts in the workflow definition work as well, but the tooling and debugging experience is a lot worse than with actual services (check documentation for Liferay Service Builder).

In general, the workflow code is not different from your standard java code: There's nothing special that I'd expect in Liferay's documentation as to interfacing with Webservices, logging etc. Liferay is using log4j in the backend, and you can do so too. I'd even expect System.out.println() to be captured in the logs, but didn't try this with the glassfish bundle.

And yes, the learning curve for implementing a new workflow system, as of yet unknown to you, can be steep. It's always best to open your first question on an unpaid community support forum with an entitlement/insult ("it's a joke") towards your system of interest. Those are the posts that *always* get the fully customized/tested source code in the thoroughly researched answers. Keep it up.

Comment: I think for example inserting a row into a datatable must be not a complex operation. Terrible documentation, no examples. Found some code sample on the web but nothing worked for me. Maybe the script correct, but the portal/java/etc config not, maybe the script wrong. No idea. I hope there is somebody out there who can give me a working example, and config step by step introduction if that needed for the running of the script.

Comment: Maybe the groovy is something like java, but in those example what I found they used " and ' too for string for example, ; or nothung after commands, etc. It seems a big mess for me at first sight.

Comment: I tried to ask same things in liferay own forum, and opened a bug ticket on their issues.liferay.com site, but after 6 days no1 replied to that ticket, on its own forum no1 replied either, so first impression about this product and "support" is more than bad. We have a duty to make something till a deadline, and had to choose some contetnt management solution in order to lower our task of programming. Now it seems this choice was bad idea, becasue without help it will steel more time than programming something by ourself.

Comment: well, if you're in a hurry, you might want to ask someone who's been there before. There's professional help for Liferay. But if you're asking for free help and nobody picks up, it might be because you just asked for "more documentation" rather than stating your problem. You say that you even posted on the forums and on the issue tracker, but you don't link to those posts. Crossreferencing would give us the opportunity to find those posts and answer on one - or combine them to get the full story and your requirements. If you don't get an answer, assume that you didn't give enough information.